# Converting URL Hack Button To Salesforce Lightning Not Auto Populating Contact And Account

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We're trying to move to lightning and one of the buttons that has to be converted  creates a new case with a new record type and auto populates fields from an old case. I used the Salesforce button converter tool to convert the buttons but it doesn't seem to work properly. The account name and contact name didn't auto populate. I tried to create a custom component to do the same but it still won't auto populate the Account Name and Contact Name. The custom component consists of a Modal that pops up a case custom component. The Account and Contact auto populate in the case custom component but when I try to display that in the Modal it doesn't work properly and show up as a lookup field. The other fields auto populate fine.

Custom Case Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasSObjectName,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Case"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
 <lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="Case" 
                           onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}" 
                           onerror="{!c.handleError}" 
                           onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}">
     <lightning:inputField fieldName="Status" />
     <lightning:inputField fieldName="AccountId" />
     <lightning:inputField fieldName="ContactId" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

`

Modal Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<!--use boolean attribute for Store true/false value,
make default to "false" so modal box are not display on the load of component. -->
<aura:attribute name="case" type="Case" />
<aura:attribute name="isOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>

<!--Use "slds-m-around_xx-large" class to add standard X-Large padding to the component--> 
<div class="slds-m-around_xx-large">

    <lightning:button variant="brand"
                      label="Edit Case"
                      title="Edit Case"
                      onclick="{! c.openModel }" />
    <!--Use aura:if tag to display Model Box, on the bese of conditions. [isOpen boolean attribute] -->   
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOpen}">

        <!--###### MODAL BOX Start######--> 
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <!-- ###### MODAL BOX HEADER Start ######-->
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"
                                          onclick="{! c.closeModel }"
                                          alternativeText="close"
                                          variant="bare-inverse"
                                          class="slds-modal__close"/>
                    <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Edit Case</h2>
                </header>
                <!--###### MODAL BOX BODY Part Start######-->
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <c:CustomAccount record="{!v.case.recordId}"/>
                </div>
                <!--###### MODAL BOX FOOTER Part Start ######-->
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <lightning:button variant="neutral" 
                                      label="Cancel"
                                      title="Cancel"
                                      onclick="{! c.closeModel }"/>
                    <lightning:button variant="brand" 
                                      label="Like and Close"
                                      title="Like and Close"
                                      onclick="{! c.likenClose }"/>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        <!--###### MODAL BOX Part END Here ######-->

    </aura:if>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the custom component and added the code from it to the Modal component and everything is working now.